# How to set default Checked in checkbox ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I'm having trouble to update the checkbox state after it's assigned with default value `checked="checked"` in React.

```
var rCheck = React.createElement('input',
    {
        type: 'checkbox',
        checked: 'checked',
        value: true
    }, 'Check here');
```

After assigning `checked="checked"`, I cannot interact the checkbox state by clicking to uncheck/check.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html Check the difference between controlled and uncontrolled components.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If the checkbox is created only with `React.createElement` then the property 
`defaultChecked` is used.

```
React.createElement('input',{type: 'checkbox', defaultChecked: false});
```

Credit to @nash_ag

Comment: this is not right you can use defaultChecked also with normal html tag, same as (class => className) and (for => htmlFor) and so on ...

Comment: @FareedAlnamrouti these statements are not mutually exclusive. Yarin is saying defaultChecked is needed if using React.createElement, not that it's used for that exclusively.

Comment: thanks, i think i misunderstood  it

Answer (score 342):

To interact with the box you need to update the state for the checkbox once you change it. And to have a default setting you can use `defaultChecked`.

An example:

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.chkbox} onChange={this.handleChangeChk} />
```

Comment: but I don't create the INPUT as class, it's created by React.createElement. So, how to set default

Comment: @YarinNim You can use `render` with the above `<input>` element. The `defaultChecked` can be provided as a param like `checked` is.

Comment: this is really strange. I am just fixing a bug that a `checkbox` is not checked by default because someone used `defaultChecked` instead of just `checked`. I changed it to `checked` and the issue is fixed. Probably something has changed since 2015 - or Formik messes up with `defaultChecked`.

Answer (score 177):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, here's a few:

**Written using State Hooks**:

```js
function Checkbox() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={checked}
        onChange={() => setChecked((state) => !state)}
      />
      Check Me!
    </label>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Checkbox />,
  document.getElementById('checkbox'),
);
```

Here is a live demo on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/foqebeyofu/edit?js,output).

**Written using Components**:

```js
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isChecked: true};
  }
  toggleChange = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({isChecked: !state.isChecked}));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={this.state.isChecked}
          onChange={this.toggleChange}
        />
        Check Me!
      </label>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Checkbox />,
  document.getElementById('checkbox'),
);
```

Here is a live demo on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hiqohaxuhe/edit?js,output).

Comment: State-full! How about stateless approach?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, throws the unhandled input error

Comment: Tested it & it's working fine on my end. Do you have any additional info @user6329530?

Comment: This works, but defaultChecked is better.

Comment: I would recommend you do the setState like this
onChange={() => setChecked(prevState => !prevState)}

Answer (score 45):

> In the React rendering lifecycle, the value attribute on form elements
>   will override the value in the DOM. With an uncontrolled component,
>   you often want React to specify the initial value, but leave
>   subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle this case, you can specify
>   a defaultValue or defaultChecked attribute instead of value.

```
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={true}
        />
```

Or

```
React.createElement('input',{type: 'checkbox', defaultChecked: true});
```

Please checkout more details regarding `defaultChecked` for checkbox below:
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: if you use checked parameter directly you can't able to uncheck it. for this defaultChecked parameter has to be used. thanks.

Answer (score 14):

in addition to the correct answer you can just do :P

```
<input name="remember" type="checkbox" defaultChecked/>
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, as this is what most people will be looking for: an alternative to the native HTML `checked`.

Answer (score 8):

Value would be whether true or false `defaultChecked={true}`

```
<input type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={true}
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
      />
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const [rememberUser, setRememberUser] = useState(true) //use false for unchecked initially


<input
   type="checkbox"
   checked={rememberUser}
   onChange={() => {
      setRememberUser(!rememberUser)
   }}
/>
```

Comment: `checked` will render readonly checkbox

Comment: No it won't, try it.

Comment: I have checked that. if you `checked` attribute in react js it will render a read-only checkbox. you cannot check or uncheck if you use the `checked` attribute. better to use defaultChecked.

Comment: @RahulMore if you use a `checked` prop **without** `onChange` it will render a read-only field.

Answer (score 5):

It`s working

```
<input type="checkbox" value={props.key} defaultChecked={props.checked} ref={props.key} onChange={this.checkboxHandler} />
```

And function init it

```
{this.viewCheckbox({ key: 'yourKey', text: 'yourText', checked: this.state.yourKey })}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may pass "true" or "" to the checked property of input checkbox. The empty quotes ("") will be understood as false and the item will be unchecked.

```
let checked = variable === value ? "true" : "";
<input
     className="form-check-input"
    type="checkbox"
    value={variable}
    id={variable}
    name={variable}
    checked={checked}
/>
<label className="form-check-label">{variable}</label>
```

Comment: You should not do this. If you pass a string to the "checked" property you will get the warning: **"Warning: Received the string `true` for the boolean attribute `checked`. Although this works, it will not work as expected if you pass the string "false". Did you mean checked={true}?"**

Answer (score 3):

I tried to accomplish this using Class component:
you can view the message for the same

.....

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        checked:true
    }
    this.handleCheck=this.handleCheck.bind(this)
}

handleCheck(){
    this.setState({
        checked:!this.state.checked
    })
}

render(){
    var msg=" "
    if(this.state.checked){
        msg="checked!"
    }else{
        msg="not checked!"
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" 
            onChange={this.handleCheck}
            defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
            />
            <p>this box is {msg}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code I did some time ago,  it might be useful.
you have to play with this line => this.state = { checked: false, checked2: true};

```
class Componente extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { checked: false, checked2: true};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);

  }  

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked      
    })
  }

  handleChange2() {
    this.setState({
        checked2: !this.state.checked2      
    })
  }

  render() {
    const togglecheck1 = this.state.checked ? 'hidden-check1' : '';
    const togglecheck2 = this.state.checked2 ? 'hidden-check2' : '';

    return <div>
        <div>
        <label>Check 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1"className="chk11" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <label>Check 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" className="chk22" checked={ this.state.checked2 } onChange={ this.handleChange2 } />
      </div>

      <div className={ togglecheck1 }>show hide div with check 1</div>
      <div className={ togglecheck2 }>show hide div with check 2</div>

    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Componente />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

CSS

```
.hidden-check1 {
  display: none;  
  }

.hidden-check2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="container">
      <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
  </div>
```

here's the codepen => http://codepen.io/parlop/pen/EKmaWM

Comment: Yet another... This is state-full approach! How about stateless?

Comment: Green, what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I felt that "defaultChecked" was not working properly with states/conditions. So I used "checked" with "onChange" for toggling the state.

Eg.

```
checked={this.state.enabled} onChange={this.setState({enabled : !this.state.enabled})}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to handle dynamic data with multiple rows, this is for     handing dynamic data.

You can check if the rowId is equal to 0.

If it is equal to 0, then you can set the state of the boolean value as true.

```
interface MyCellRendererState {
    value: boolean;
}
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: props.value ? props.value : false
        };
        this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
    }
handleCheckboxChange() {
        this.setState({ value: !this.state.value });
    };
render() {
        const { value } = this.state;
        const rowId = this.props.rowIndex
        if (rowId === 0) {
           this.state = {
             value : true }
        }
        return ( 
          <div onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}>
            <input 
            type="radio" 
            checked={this.state.value}
            name="print"
            /> 
          </div>
         )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it too hard. First, understand a simple example given below. It will be clear to you. In this case, just after pressing the checkbox, we will grab the value from the state(initially it's false), change it to other value(initially it's true) & set the state accordingly. If the checkbox is pressed for the second time, it will do the same process again. Grabbing the value (now it's true), change it(to false) & then set the state accordingly(now it's false again. The code is shared below.

Part 1

```
state = {
  verified: false
} // The verified state is now false
```

Part 2

```
verifiedChange = e => {
  // e.preventDefault(); It's not needed
  const { verified } = e.target;
  this.setState({
    verified: !this.state.verified // It will make the default state value(false) at Part 1 to true 
  });
};
```

Part 3

```
  <form> 
      <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="verified"
          id="verified"
          onChange={this.verifiedChange} // Triggers the function in the Part 2
          value={this.state.verified}
      />
      <label for="verified">
      <small>Verified</small>
      </label>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="display__lbl_input">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={this.handleChangeFilGasoil}
                value="Filter Gasoil"
                name="Filter Gasoil"
                id=""
              />
              <label htmlFor="">Filter Gasoil</label>
            </div>

handleChangeFilGasoil = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked){
        this.setState({
            checkedBoxFG:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.checkedBoxFG)
    }
    else{
     this.setState({
        checkedBoxFG : ''
     })
     console.log(this.state.checkedBoxFG)
    }
  };
```

Comment: Some accompanying text would help to understand what your code snippet is meant to do and how it relates to the question about ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state var "enableSwitch" and a function "handleSwitch" to handle your default checked Switch:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switchId" checked={this.state.enableSwitch} onClick={this.handleSwitch}/>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="switchId">switch text</label>
</div>
```

Here's the function which inverts the variable if the user clicks on the switch:

```
handleSwitch = (e) => {
   this.setState({ enableSwitch: !this.state.enableSwitch });
}
```

I know it's a late reply to an old question, but this short solution may help other users.

Answer (score -2):

```
 <div className="form-group">
          <div className="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="" onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}  />Flagged</label>
            <br />
            <label><input type="checkbox" value=""  />Un Flagged</label>
          </div>
        </div
```

> handleInputChange(event){
>
> ```
> console.log("event",event.target.checked)   }
> ```

the Above handle give you the value of true or false upon checked or unChecked

Answer (score -2):

I set the state as any[] type. and in the constructor set the state to null.

```
onServiceChange = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    const index = this.state.services.indexOf(value);
    const services = this.state.services.filter(item => item !== value);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        services: index === -1 ? prevState.services.push(value) && prevState.services : this.state.services.filter(item => item !== value)
    }))
}
```

In the input element

this.onServiceChange(e)}/>
 this.onServiceChange(e)}/>
 this.onServiceChange(e)}/>
 this.onServiceChange(e)}/>

I figured it out after some time. Thought it might help y'all :)