# How to make default checked for radio buttons in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to make the radio button checked if the initial value is true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default Checked in checkbox REACT js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-react-js)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `defaultChecked` prop

Answer (score 78):

Using the `defaultChecked` property, available for `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="radio">` - https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" value="1" defaultChecked />
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" value="3" />
```

Comment: could you tell me how do I get the value of first input that is defaultChecked with using any onClick or onChange listeners ?

Comment: doesn't work, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283842/9186481 works instead

Comment: @UMR `checked` takes precedence over `defaultChecked`. You shouldn't use both at the same time. This approach is intended for uncontrolled components only - https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: How would one use this when generating multiple radio buttons via map()? e.g.
`{[1, 2, 3].map((num) => (<input type="radio" name="group1" value={num} />))}`

Adding `defaultChecked` sets the last radio button created as the checked value, where I was wanting to have the first value set.

Comment: @Swirle13 an attribute without a value, such as `defaultChecked` in the example above, is a shorthand for the value `true`. So, to use the attribute conditionally, you can assign a boolean value to it. In your case `defaultChecked={num === 1}`.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes the issue can be fixed by removing the name attribute and instead using a conditional checked value:

```
<li>
    <label>
    <input
        type="radio"
        value="medium"
        checked={this.state.size === "medium"}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    Medium
    </label>
</li>

<li>
    <label>
    <input
        type="radio"
        value="large"
        checked={this.state.size === "large"}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    Large
    </label>
</li>
```

Source Here: https://magnusbenoni.com/radio-buttons-react/

Answer (score 6):

Add the `checked` attribute to your radio button, e.g. `checked={field.input.value}`. [[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/juwemes/edit?js,output)]

Comment: i need it default checked when it has `initialValues`

Answer (score 3):

Adding a defaultChecked should be the idea here and not the checked value.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question under @Hugo Silva's top answer.

I was looking to set the default to "1" out of a list of 5, and I generated the list of each with a map() call to reduce written code. This led to the last element being selected for the `defaultChecked` value, which I didn't want.

My solution is as follows:

```js
{[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((num) => (
  <input
    defaultChecked={num === 1}  // returns bool, only true for first input
    type="radio"
    name="group1"
    value={num}
  />
))}
```