# Checkbox checked in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the javascript function .checked() in React.js like this :

```
componentDidMount () {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
}
```

But I have an error in my console : "la propriété 'checked' n'existe pas sur le type HTMLlement"

How can I use this in React.js ?

Thank you

Comment: In React you have to update the state to re-render the component. Please post more code.

Comment: why you want to do it like this? react provides a better way of controlling elements, simply use `<input checked={true} onChange={....}/>` for [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), if you want to use [uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) then use `<input defaultChecked={true}/> `

Comment: I would rely on your component state for the checkbox status, instead of modifying any properties of the DOM by hand. Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-react-js) question and answer, since it handles a really similar problem.

Comment: @MayankShukla Thank you for your answer , it was very simple .. and I didn't think about it ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

```
<div className='container'>
    <input type='checkbox' ref='myAwesomeCheckbox' id={'scales'} />
    <label fhtmlForor="scales">Scales</label>
</div>

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.refs.myAwesomeCheckbox.checked = true;
}
```