# React: How to uncheck all radio inputs initially

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have this issue. I'm creating a survey with MERN stack that downloads the data from the server and displays questions and stores the answers on the server. My issue is that some questions have options checked initially. I have checked everything and does not know what's causing these to check. So, I want to uncheck all options (radio and checkboxes) initially when the parent component mounts. When I use 'checked=true', then I cannot change it afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default Checked in checkbox REACT js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-react-js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultChecked`

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={false} ... />
```