# React with bootstrap checkbox disabled attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
<input {...{type: 'checkbox', name, checked, readOnly: true, disabled: true}} />
```

Can someone tell me why my checkbox is not being disabled?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it might make sense to check what devtools say

Comment: i don't see any error or warning on devtools

Comment: Use React.createElement('input',{type: 'checkbox', defaultChecked: false}); thats works fine. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-reactjs

Comment: [It should work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/23xv3m73r0). Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the onClick handler was one level above the input tag (parent div). 
If you do it like this it should work as expected:

```
<input {...{type: 'checkbox', name, checked, onClick: this.onChange, disabled: false}} />
```