# ReactJS - Checkbox column in react-table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have added an editable react-table (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/kitchen-sink) to my project and everything works fine. But when I added a column with checkboxes, and tick the checkboxes and go to a different page (or sort or search) and come back, ticks are gone. This is how I have added the checkbox to the 'columns' field,

```
{
   Header: 'On Leave',
   accessor: 'onLeave',
   Filter: SelectColumnFilter,
   filter: 'includes',
   disableGroupBy: true,
   Cell: row => { return(
            <div style={{'text-align':'center'}}>
              <input type="checkbox" 
                value={row.value == "Yes" ? "on" : "off"} 
                onBlur={(event) => updateMyData(parseInt(row.row.id), row.column.id, event.target.checked ? "Yes" : "No")}  />
            </div>)},
}
```

updateMyData() is fired when focus is lost from checkbox and console.log prints correct data,

```
0 : 0 : onLeave : Yes
1 : 1 : onLeave : Yes
2 : 2 : onLeave : Yes
3 : 3 : onLeave : Yes
4 : 4 : onLeave : Yes
```

updateMyData() is as follows,

```
// When our cell renderer calls updateMyData, we'll use
// the rowIndex, columnId and new value to update the
// original data

const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {


    // We also turn on the flag to not reset the page
    skipResetRef.current = true
    setData(old =>
      old.map((row, index) => {
        if (index === rowIndex) { console.log(index + " : " +  rowIndex + " : " + columnId + " : " + value););
          return {
            ...row,
            [columnId]: value,
          }
        }
        return row
      })
    )

}
```

Why is the checkbox values not saved in 'data' field? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with using checkbox 'value' attribute. Instead of that, using 'defaultChecked' solved the problem,

```
Cell: row => {
  return(
    <div style={{'text-align':'center'}}>
      <input type="checkbox" 
        defaultChecked={row.value == "Yes" ? true : false} 
        onBlur={(event) => updateMyData(parseInt(row.row.id), row.column.id, event.target.checked ? "Yes" : "No")}  />
    </div>)}
```

This question has more details,
[How to set default Checked in checkbox ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-reactjs)