# Make Checkbox required in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to make checkbox mandatory field in react js.

I am new to reactjs but i have an idea that i should do it using length . Below is the code:

```
<CheckboxGroup name="zones" value={this.state.zones} onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}>
       {(Checkbox) => (
         <>
                                                   
            {this.state.zones_to_render_to_render.map((zone, key) =>
              <Col key={key} lg="10">
                  <label >
                         <Checkbox value={zone.zone_id} />{zone.zone_name}
                  </label>
             </Col>
                                                            

          )}
                                                        
       </>
     )}
</CheckboxGroup>
```

How to check using length?

Comment: Look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-reactjs . You can do it just using false/true.

Comment: It looks like you're using AntD. You can use their [Forms API](https://ant.design/components/form/) to accomplish this and handle the rest of the form's functionality, or look into a solution like [Formik](https://github.com/formium/formik) which can also handle validation for you. There is simply not enough code here to determine what making it "required" means yet.

Comment: You can use true/false to do that. You do not need to use length here. You can create a function, let's say: invalid() where you check whether your checkbox is checked or not. Then if invalid, do not submit the form, and you can show a pop up error.

Answer (score 0):

The component `<Checkbox />` has a prop **required** which is false by default you can make the checkbox mandatory by passing it true.

```
<Checkbox value={zone.zone_id} required={true} />
```

Comment: It is making to select all the checkbox field. I want to select any 1 field.

Comment: In the map function, key is basically the index of the `zones`, you can conditionally make the checkbox mandatory by passing some condition to the required prop.
Below are some examples:
1. To make the first checkbox mandatory, you ll have to do 
     required={key === 0}
2. To make the last checkbox mandatory, you ll have to do 
    required = {key === this.state.zones_to_render_to_render.length}