# How to set default value in checkbox and radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I am making a simple react application where I have some default values to set to the input fields.

Here there are three input fields,

```
-> Textbox   = UserName

-> Checkbox  = Relocation

-> Radio     = ContactMode
```

Their respective values are,

```
 {
    UserName: "Test User",
    Relocation: true,
    ContactMode: "Email",
 }
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    UserName: "Test User",
    Relocation: true,
    ContactMode: "Email",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormValue({
      ...formValue,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  
  const submitData = () => {
    console.log(formValue)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label> User Name </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="UserName"
          value={formValue.UserName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label> Willing to relocate? </label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="Relocation"
          value={formValue.Relocation}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label> Contact Mode </label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="ContactMode"
          value={`Email`}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />{" "}
        Email
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="ContactMode"
          value={`Text`}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />{" "}
        Text
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="ContactMode"
          value={`Both`}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />{" "}
        Both
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="button" onClick={submitData}> Submit </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Problem:**

-> In the above eg.., Only the text field value is got set but checkbox and radio button values not got set by default.

**Expectaion:**

-> All the three input fields needs to get set by its default values.

-> On changing any input field and upon clicking submit button, the latest changes needs to get logged via `formValue` ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set default Checked in checkbox ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use checked

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    UserName: "Test User",
    Relocation: true,
    ContactMode: "Email",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormValue({
      ...formValue,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  
  const handleCheckedChange = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;
    setFormValue({
      ...formValue,
      [name]: checked,
    });
  }
  
  const submitData = () => {
    console.log(formValue)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label> User Name </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="UserName"
          value={formValue.UserName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label> Willing to relocate? </label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="Relocation"
          checked={formValue.Relocation}
          onChange={handleCheckedChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label> Contact Mode </label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="ContactMode"
          checked={formValue.ContactMode === "Email"}
          value={`Email`}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />{" "}
        Email
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="ContactMode"
          checked={formValue.ContactMode  === "Text"}
          value={`Text`}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />{" "}
        Text
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="ContactMode"
          checked={formValue.ContactMode  === "Both"}
          value={`Both`}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />{" "}
        Both
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="button" onClick={submitData}> Submit </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Unable to uncheck the checkbox.. If I uncheck the checkbox then false needs to be stored in  Relocation..

Comment: Isn't possible to handle it in ```handleInputChange``` itself?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent `value` property for a checkbox is `checked`:

```
<input
          type="checkbox"
          name="Relocation"
          checked={formValue.Relocation}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    UserName: "Test User",
    Relocation: true,
    ContactMode: "Email",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormValue({
      ...formValue,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  
  const submitData = () => {
    console.log(formValue)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label> User Name </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="UserName"
          value={formValue.UserName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label> Willing to relocate? </label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="Relocation"
          value={formValue.Relocation}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label> Contact Mode </label>
        <input
      type="radio"
      name="ContactMode"
      value={`Email`}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      checked={formValue.ContactMode==="Email"}
    />{" "}
    Email
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="ContactMode"
      value={`Text`}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      checked={formValue.ContactMode==="Text"}
    />{" "}
    Text
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="ContactMode"
      value={`Both`}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      checked={formValue.ContactMode==="Both"}
      
    />{" "}
    Both
    <br />
    <br />
        <button type="button" onClick={submitData}> Submit </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Isn't possible to handle it in ```handleInputChange``` itself?