# Reactjs checkbox check from button click

Tags: reactjs

```
    <input className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                                               
                      />
<input type="button" onClick={()=>clickHandle()}/>
```

When I click the button, I want to change the check property of the checkbox. But the checked property or defaultChecked properties do not work in this regard. What can I do about it?

Comment: Please add some more context to your question (the basic structure of the component). Also, there is no checkbox in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want the status of the checkbox to change when the button is clicked.

If I understood correctly, this is probably what you wanted.

```
export default function App() {
  const [chkValue, setChkValue] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input className="form-control" type="checkbox" checked={chkValue}/>
       <input type="button" value="click" onClick={()=>setChkValue(!chkValue)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Oke it's worked. but it breaks the form-control

Answer (score -2):

You have a type text input and a type button input. There is no checkbox there. You'd need a type checkbox input and then try this answer [How to set default Checked in checkbox ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174317/how-to-set-default-checked-in-checkbox-reactjs)

Edit:

Wrong link for setting checked value. The link explains how to set the default. [This code snippet](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) has an example of setting a checkbox value dynamically.

Comment: Isn't defaultChecked properties, initialize value?

Comment: @FatihBaytar you are right sorry. checked is the correct property. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs this link has an example in the code with a checkbox and how to set it correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I think my main problem is with dynamically generated checkboxes.